# Alignment of characters in Notepad++

Tags: matlab, alignment, notepad++, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I just wondered why my m-files from MATLAB look so different when I open them with Notepad++ instead of the built-in MATLAB Editor.

It seems that in the MATLAB Editor each character has the same width. Not so in Notepad++ (even I change the language to "M").

Here's a screenshot from a file opened in Notepad++ (left) and in the MATLAB Editor (right).

[image]

In the MATLAB Editor all the characters in column X are exactly one below the other. They aren't in Notepad++.

I just played a bit with the tab preferences, without any success.

Is there a way to get the alignment of columns in Notepad++ the same as in the MATLAB Editor ...at least for m-files?

Comment: Perhaps set your font to monospace? I've seen a couple of questions regarding this. A suggested solution from one of these questions: 1. Go to Settings->Styler Configurator.
2.  Set Global Styles->Default Style->Font Name to "Courier".

Comment: Just out fo curiosity, which theme are you using in Notepad++?

Comment: @WouterKuijsters it increases the spaces, but alignment still isn't "correct"

Comment: @kkuilla I#m using the "Obsidian" style in Np++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because your MATLAB Editor is set to use a monospaced font such as Courier (i.e. a font where all the characters are designed to have exactly the same width), but your Notepad++ is not.

In Notepad++, you can set the font with the menu Settings -> Style Configurator. Select "MATLAB" from the language list (or in fact you may like to select "Global Styles", to do this for all languages), and set the font to a monospaced font such as Courier.

Alternatively, you may like to download a more modern programming font such as Consolas, ProFont, Monofur, Proggy, or Inconsolata. These are all monospaced, and nicer than Courier. You can use the in both Notepad++ and the MATLAB Editor.

It's possible that another issue might be that you have tab characters in your code, which are displaying with a variable width in Notepad++. You can make sure that MATLAB replaces tab characters with spaces in the MATLAB preferences (MATLAB->Editor/Debugger/Tab). To check whether you have tab characters, open the file in Notepad++ and select View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters. Tab characters will display as a short arrow, and space characters will display as a little dot. If you need to change all the tabs to spaces in an existing file, Notepad++ can do this with Edit->Blank Operations->Tab to Space.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

To add to Sam's answer, choosing a monospaced font specific to your environment's language is recommended. For instance, Courier New on Japanese language may not have the desired result. Choose MS Gothic (for [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows)) or Osaka (for [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X)) instead.